# Как максимально равномерно распределить число по массиву Java и JS?

Tags: javascript, java, distribution, currency

**Подскажите алгоритм как можно распределить n сумму денег, на количество месяцев без округления.**

Например, дана сумма **100**, её нужно распределить **на 12** месяцев. То есть на выходе нужен массив из 12 элементов.
Если просто поделить 100 на 12 то получим ~8,333333333333333 в каждом элементе, что при расчёте денежных сумм не приемлемо.
Нужно получить максимально равномерно распределённые числа до 2х знаков после запятой.
На **js** такую возможность даёт библиотека **currency** методом distribute. Он смещает остатки к началу массива.

**Подскажите подобную реализацию на java или сам алгоритм на js**

Comment: Определитесь, java или js? Это прям два кардинально разных языка, реализация может сильно отличаться.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение работает в целых числах - `value * factor`. Слева сумма, которую распределяем, справа множитель для перевода рублей в копейки.

В цикле от суммы отнимаем округлённые части. Распределение получается максимально равномерным.

```js
const distribute = (value, n) => {
    const factor = 100;
    let sum = value * factor;
    const distribution = [];
    for (let i = n; i > 0; --i) {
        const v = Math.round(sum / i);
        distribution.push(v / factor);
        sum -= v;
    }
    return distribution;
};

console.log(distribute(100, 12).join(' '));
```

Тоже самое на Java:

```
    public static double[] distribute(double value, int n) {
        final double factor = 100;
        double sum = value * factor;
        double[] distribution = new double[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            double v = Math.round(sum / (n - i));
            distribution[i] = v / factor;
            sum -= v;
        }
        return distribution;
    }
```